# Using OCR-B as default TT font with T1 fontenc

Tags: fonts

I would like to use the OCR-B font provided by the `ocr` package as the default mono font in my document. Because of other font choices, I would also like to use the `T1` fontenc.

The below MWE compiles with this warning and the "TT Test" text comes out in Computer Modern:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ocrb/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 9.
```

```
\documentclass[convert, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{ocr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{ocrb}

\begin{document}
Roman Test
\texttt{TT Test}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output showing both lines in Roman instead of the second line in OCR-B]

This works properly without the `T1` fontenc.

Is it possible to mix font encodings in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can locally switch to OT1 encoding. Be aware that this means that Umlauts and other chars with accents are built with accents and so don't copy&paste correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\let\ttfamily\ocrfamily
\begin{document}
Roman 
\texttt{TT Test äöüßé}
\end{document}
```

[image]